# JPA how to remove parent without delete children?

Tags: jpa, cascade, one-to-many

I'm trying to remove a parent, but I keep getting a Foreign Key violation. If I put Cascade.ALL in the parent, it delete the children too.  And it's now what I want.

I have my parent class : Docteur

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Patient
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH}, orphanRemoval=false, mappedBy="docteur")
    private List patients;
```

and my children are : Patient

I put that

```
    @ManyToOne()
    private Docteur docteur;
```

but in my case, the patient choul only have one Docteur.

In my Manager class.  I try lot of things that didn't work

here my latest version

```
Clinique clinique = read(clinique_ID);
Docteur docteur = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getDocteur", Docteur.class).setParameter("clinique_ID", clinique_ID).setParameter("docteur_ID", docteur_ID).getSingleResult();

clinique.getDocteurs().remove(docteur);

entityManager.merge(clinique);

entityManager.persist(clinique);
```

Here the error that I get :

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jerabi_asteriskdb/Patient`, CONSTRAINT `FK340C82E5A10F077E` FOREIGN KEY (`docteur_DOCTEUR_ID`) REFERENCES `Docteur` (`DOCTEUR_ID`))

Answer (score 6):

You get a foreign key violation because the database checks that every docteur_id in the patient table refers to a valid docteur. This is the whole point of foreign keys. The database ensures that you don't delete a docteur still referenced by patients.

In order to delete your docteur, you must ensure that no other record in the database references this docteur_id. So, you must update all the patients of this docteur and set their docteur_id to null :

```
Docteur docteur = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getDocteur", Docteur.class).setParameter("clinique_ID", clinique_ID).setParameter("docteur_ID", docteur_ID).getSingleResult();

for (Patient patient : docteur.getPatients()) {
    patient.setDocteur(null);
}
docteur.patients.clear();
clinique.getDocteurs().remove(docteur);
```

Also, all the attached (persistent) entities are automatically updated by Hibernate. There is no need to persist and merge them. Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-overview.

Comment: Sorry, I referred to Hibernate, and maybe you're using another JPA implementation. The answer still stands, though.

Comment: If you have to explicitly set the Docteur objects to null then doesn't that defeat the purpose of using JPA to do cassade deletes? If that's the case then I think writing my own delete SQL is better and more str8 forward.

Comment: @Mr.PortStJoe a cascade delete would delete the patients of the docteur when deleting the docteur. The OP wants to delete the docteur but leave the patients in the database, without docteur. There's no cascading here.

Answer (score 0):

So that a relation database can enforce data integrity, references to dependent rows in referencing tables have to be considered. SQL 2003 specifies 5 different referential actions:

1. CASCADE: dependent rows get deleted
2. RESTRICT: delete fails with an error
3. NO ACTION: like delete, but allows triggers to run first, in case they fix the error
4. SET NULL: sets the referencing columns to null (at least one column must be nullable)
5. SET DEFAULT: sets the referencing columns to their default value (which will then reference another existing row in the table, unless at least one default is NULL)

Comment: the problem it's how to do that in JPA 2.0.  plain SQL would had been easy.